# Mmenu -Problems with change width

Tags: mmenu

G'day!
I'm afraid to be pushy and impolite, but I can't solve 2 problems

1. Could you tell me please how to change the width of Mmenu (ver 9.x.x)
2. Is it possible to use (and how) Mmenu (ver 9.x) in Bootstrap (3.x, 4.x)
   Thank you

I hope on  your help